# Jquery and Regex numeric check

Tags: jquery, regex

Hi all having a little problem with regex and Jquery in checking that a date will work correctly.

Currently it doesn't accept the number 01 but does 02+ but works as expected with ranges above 31.

this is the js fiddle page. http://jsfiddle.net/b3aHt/

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`01` fails because of `dob < 2`.

I don't think regular expressions make for a very neat solution here. I would rather test

```
if(dob.length != 2 || isNaN(dob) || dob < 0 || dob > 31) {
   // not between 01 and 31
}
```

Comment: oh that was just to check that dobs length was greater than to should that be dob.length < 2?

Comment: Thanks David. I like your neater solution too.